# WebBrowser DocumentText encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, browser

I have come across something strange and I'd like your opinion.

There is a webpage which contains a `span` element with some greek text in the `InnerText` and `InnerHtml` attributes.

The encoding of the page is **Greek(Windows)**.

My `if` statement is:

```cs
if (mySpan != null && mySpan.InnerText.Contains(greekText))
```

This line works 100%, but my previous non-working code was:

```cs
if (mySpan != null && browser.DocumentText.Contains(greekText))
```

This line did not work, and when I clicked on the preview withing the debugger I noticed that the greek text was unreadable (strange symbols instead of greek characters). However, all of other elements that contained greek text were successfully read by the application, that is I could save their attributes in variables and use them. Is there any explanation why `DocumentText` failed and `InnerText` succeeded?

Comment: can you please show how you are getting the value of `mySpan` ?

Comment: `HtmlElement mySpan = browser.Document.GetElementById(mySpanId);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source for `WebBrowser.DocumentText` it would appear it uses UTF8 Encoding by default:

```
public string DocumentText
{
  get
  {
    Stream documentStream = this.DocumentStream;
    if (documentStream == null)
      return "";
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(documentStream);
    documentStream.Position = 0L;
    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
  }
```

That is, using a `StreamReader` without specifying an encoding will assume UTF8 Encoding.

See [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/b4a1024c-5c09-47fa-a24c-a87f55adb383/) for getting around this issue

I can only assume using `browser.Document.GetElementById(mySpanId)` respects the stated encoding of the page which is why you see it correctly when using this call.

Comment: Checking at the moment, I'll be back to tell you what happened.

Comment: what is the value of `browser.Document.Encoding` in your case? that should be passed to StreamReader (in the `WebBrowser` class but it is not)

Comment: `browser.Document.DefaultEncoding` is Windows-1253

Comment: ok, so you will have to handle the decoding yourself from `document.DocumentStream` if you want the "real" `document.DocumentText`

Comment: The solution is in my question, I just could not understand why this happens. But your answer is correct anyway, even if I don't handle the decoding myself.